# How do I run an executable jar in Jenkins workspace directory

Tags: logging, jenkins-pipeline, sh, executable-jar, jenkins-cli

How do I run an executable agent-cli.jar located in my Jenkins workspace directory called "reports"
I have a declarative pipeline that I'm using but the jar can't be executed

```
 stage('Execute Jar'){
      steps{
            sh "chmod +rx logger_agent_cli.sh; ./logger_agent_cli.sh 5"
          }
    }
```

and this is my .sh file

```
java -jar $WORKSPACE/reports/agent-cli.jar \
--test_type=SmokeTest  \
--tool=CUCUMBERJSON \
--file=${WORKSPACE}/cucumber-report.json
```

/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was missing #!/bin/bash   at the start of the .sh file and also removed / at the bottom of the file.